# Parsing multiple JSONs from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, android, sockets

I've got pure and simple Java Nio Socket Server. Data transfer realized with JSON. With 1 clien all work fine, but when i am trying to start workload test - some problem appeared. Here is my method for parsing incoming ByteBuffer (MessageFromBuffer is just a wrapper for byte[]):

```
private JSONObject parseIncomingMessageToJson(MessageFromBuffer messageFromBuffer) {
        int size = messageFromBuffer.getSize();
        byte[] data = messageFromBuffer.getData();

        byte[] dataCopy = new byte[size];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataCopy, 0, size);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonMessage = null;

        try {
            jsonMessage = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new String(dataCopy));
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            System.out.println("Error formatting incoming message to json:  " + new String(messageFromBuffer.getData()));
        }

        return jsonMessage;
    }
```

When buffer cosists of only one json entity - all works fine. But during 100 clients attack, buffer can be populated with multiple json enities, as shown (All testing clients send same data):

```
Error formatting incoming message to json:  {"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
{"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
{"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
{"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
{"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
{"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
{"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
{"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
{"TYPE":"REGISTRATION","LOGIN":"Padre","PASSWORD":"3214"}
```

Method throws exception and returns with nothing. After each read from SOcketChanel i clear buffer - so all those messages are lost. Are there some techniques for proper JSON parsing in such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you posted it looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178651/how-to-parse-multiple-json-objects-with-no-name) since the outputs are separated with a nextline character. You could make use of it to split the string into an array of serialized json responses.

Then you could individually parse them into json objects.